# Calculate average age of members (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create the average age of my members.
I already managed to get an array of all the date of births and found an easy way to calculate a birthday. But I don't manage to combine it.

My 'date of birth' - array:

```
$results = array();

$dob_array = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT dob_array FROM members");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dob_array)){
        $results[] = $row;
    }
```

The calculation of the age:

```
$today = new DateTime();
$birthdate = new DateTime("1991-01-01");
$interval = $today->diff($birthdate);
echo $interval->format('%y years');
```

Calculation average of my age-array:

```
$average = array_sum($array) / count($array);
```

Comment: And what happens next.Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might be done with direct sql (using [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) and [`AVG()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) functions):

```
SELECT AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, `dob`, NOW())) as `average` FROM `member`;
```

Comment: To get a more accurate result use and `interval` of `DAY` and divide by 365. `AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `date_of_birth`, NOW())/365)`.

Answer (score 0):

This might the one:

```
SELECT AVG(DOB_COLUMN_NAME) from TABLE NAME
```

Comment: This will give the avg date of birth, not the age.